# Reset Password with RSA Keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

- I wrote a module to reset your password using RSA keys.
- The code will send an email to the user with a link to reset his
  password.
- The user then will click on the link, that will send him back to the 
  MVC web site.
- The link is composed of 3 parts: URL / ID / Public RSA Key
- I am using MVC with routes

Issue 1: RSA Keys have slashes "/", therefore I had to URL Encode they key.

Issue 2: When the Key is encoded and the user clicks on it, MVC gives me the following error

**The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence**

Does anyone know how to deal with RSA keys inside MVC using routes?

Of course without opening the door to HTML injection......

Comment: `<system.webServer><security><requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" /></security></system.webServer>` however this does expose security vulnerabilities to your application. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7742208/426894

Comment: That will open the door for HTML Injection....

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739233/double-escape-sequence-inside-a-url-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured. Also, does "MVC" mean something different in ASP.net? I only know of it in the meaning of the Model-View-Controller design pattern, which can't exactly do any error-throwing of its own.

Comment: @JAB "MVC" is a generic reference to ASP.net MVC Framework.  Many people don't actually realize the framework is named after a design pattern, and use the shorthand.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you passing this information as query string parameters. Scott Hanselman explains in details in [`this blog post`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx).

Quote from his conclusion:

> After ALL this effort to get crazy stuff in the Request Path, it's
>   worth mentioning that simply keeping the values as a part of the Query
>   String (remember WAY back at the beginning of this post?) is easier,
>   cleaner, more flexible, and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable that feature with the following code in the web.config.  Please note, however, this may be a security risk, as it allows someone to append javascript double escaped elements to a page url, as many others have commented.

```
<system.webserver>
    <modules runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests="true">
        <security>
            <requestfiltering allowdoubleescaping="true">
            </requestfiltering>
        </security>
    </modules>
</system.webserver>
```

your better option by far is to have your link go to a form which asks for the RSA to be pasted in and submitted back.  A small bit more work for your end users, but drastically more secure.