# Dotnet core + (plus) sign in Web API routing

Tags: iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I work on web API project in the dotnet core and check user mobile number exists check.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("mobile/exist/{mobile}/{id:int?}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MobileExist(string mobile, int? id)
    {
        return Json(await _userService.MobileExist(mobile, id));
    }
}
```

Request URL:

> http://localhost:3364/api/user/mobile/exist/+123456

When I request above URL with the plus sign it given an error.

The Same URL without + sign it's working good.

I try with encoded **+** sign with **%2B** but it not working

**How can I request with plus sign?**

Comment: What is the route that you have defined for your controller? Can you show that code as well?

Comment: I added UserController.

Comment: Strange - it works on my machine.

Comment: For me, it gave an error. The make sure you added (+) sign in URL request. and also I have `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an IIS issue:

Please look at the following post:

[double escape sequence inside a url : The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739233/double-escape-sequence-inside-a-url-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured)

If you try to run your app with Kestrel, you will see that it works.
For IIS, you will need to add the following section in you web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```