# C# .Net How to Encode URL space with %20 instead of +

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How to encode query string space with `%20` instead of `+` ? 
Because `System.Web  HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` gives the space with `+`.

Comment: In modern .Net Core UrlEncode uses %20

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim might you be a little more specific than "modern" please - I am running with target framework netcoreapp3.1 and HttpUtility.UrlEncode(somestring) is giving me + instead of %20

Comment: .Net core 6 still gives + instead of %20

Answer (score 102):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var encoded = Uri.EscapeDataString("How to encode");
```

OUTPUT:

```
How%20to%20encode
```

Comment: Uri.EscapeUriString has been marked as obsolete as of 9/15/2021 since it "can corrupt the Uri string in some cases." As @Robert Koernke said, the new recommended approach by Microsoft is Uri.EscapeDataString()