# c# - Handle empty spaces in file name while providing the file path as a link

Tags: c#

I am developing an internal application which sends email to the users with the link to the training dcouments.

These documnets are placed in internal share drive, few of these documents have empty space in their names and thats causing the problem.

The path looks like `\\Users\shared\Training\Database\Oracle\Docs\Oracle Database Admin.docx` and i tried to replace empty space with %20 but still it doesn't work.. In the email link the path is trimmed to `\\Users\shared\Training\Database\Oracle\Docs\Oracle`

```
Public string GetMediaPath(int itemCode)
{
 string path = _dbContext.TraningMedias.Where( s => s.ItemCode == itemCode).Select(a => a.Path).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
 path.replace(" ", "%20");
 return path;
}
```

I dont understand why the replace function is not working in this case.

Comment: You'll probably need to directly set the link in the email body HTML. What's happening is that your email client is changing the hyperlink. How are the emails being sent?

Comment: sending mail via SMTP , this link is being sent in the email body its self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are *immutable*, and `Replace` returns a string, so try this:

```
path = path.Replace(" ", "%20");
```

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the spaces in your link text, use an opening and closing chevron

```
Public string GetMediaPath(int itemCode)
{
 string path = "<"+ _dbContext.TraningMedias.Where( s => s.ItemCode == itemCode).Select(a => a.Path).FirstOrDefault().ToString() + ">";

 return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

The below code will remove all invalid filename characters from the path.

```
 path =string.Concat(path.Split(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()));
```

Dont forget to include System.IO namespace.

Thanks

Comment: This is removing all the  //  in the path and making the entire path as a single string which is making it invalid path

Answer (score 0):

You can try url encode adn get rid off spaces and others speacial characters.

```
path= HttpUtility.UrlDecode(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the raw file path string to a proper URI, like this:

```cs
string fileUrl = new System.Uri("c:\\foo\\my document.docx").AbsoluteUri
```

which will give you this string:
"file:///c:/foo/my%20document.docx"

Answer (score 0):

Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46338134/13896538)

In your case:

```
path = Uri.EscapeUriString(path);
```