# Receiving a magic login link on Azure without allowing double escaping

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

Trying to implement a magic link login on an Asp.net core 2.1 Web app. Works like a charm locally, however when deploying to Azure I get an error message: `The request contained a double escape sequence and request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny double escape sequences

MagicLinkSender.cs

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(
    user: user,  
    tokenProvider: "MagicLinkTokenProvider", 
    purpose: "magic-link"
);

var magiclink = _urlHelper.Link(
            routeName: "MagicLinkRoute", 
            values: new { userid = user.Id, token = token,  });
```

AccountController

```
[HttpGet("/magic/{userid}/{token}", Name = "MagicLinkRoute")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MagicLogin([FromRoute]string userid, [FromRoute]string token )
{
    // Sign the user out if they're signed in
    if(_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    }

    var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userid);
    if(user != null)
    {
        token = token.Replace("%2F", "/");
        var isValid = await _signInManager.UserManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(
            user: user,
            tokenProvider: "MagicLinkTokenProvider",
            purpose: "magic-link",
            token: token
        );
        if(isValid)
        {
            await _signInManager.UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);
        }
    }

    return RedirectToPage("/Profile/Index");
}
```

Seems like I can get around this with allowing doublescaping in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

However this seems to open some [security holes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739233/double-escape-sequence-inside-a-url-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured). Are there better alternatives to get this working on Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to use parameters from querystring instead of route seems to solve this problem when deploying to Azure.

```
[HttpGet("/magic", Name = "MagicLinkRoute")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MagicLogin([FromQuery]string userid, [FromQuery]string token )
{
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Some characters require additional configuration depending on your hosting environment:

To allow '+' in item names in ASP.NET 2.0 and 4.0 set the configuration\in your web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

To allow '&' and '%' in ASP.NET 4.0 set the configurationin your web.config file.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime  requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
</system.web>
```

To allow trailing dots ('.') in ASP.NET 4.0 set configuration in your web.config file.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
</system.web>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/special_characters_asp_net_iis) and this [one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/942076/error-message-when-you-visit-a-web-site-that-is-hosted-on-iis-7-0-http).

Comment: Please note that this is asp.net core question.