# Action method with JSON API call gives 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I am doing an API call which is working fine at localhost but when I run it on the server, the page first is asking for an authorization (screenshot attached). If I skip the step, I get the following error.

[image]

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You
>   do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

If I supply server admin credential I get this:

> Configuration Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file:
>   Failed to start monitoring changes to 'C:...\test' because access is
>   denied.
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

I have `customErrors mode = "Off"` already set up in server's `web.config` file.

```
<system.web>
   ...
   <customErrors mode="Off" />
   ...
</system.web>
```

Below is my code:

```
public ActionResult ApiTest{
   var baseUri = "https://<apiurl>/products";
   var json = "{\"requestList\": {\"access_id\": \"access_id\", \"access_key\": \"access_key\", \"clientIpAdr\": \"x.x.x.x\", \"currency\": \"USD\", \"lang\": \"en\", \"filters\": { \"product_category\": 1, \"reference_no\": \"xxxxxx\" } } }";
   var result = "";

   var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseUri);
   request.ContentType = "application/json";
   request.Accept = "text/json";
   request.Method = "POST";
   request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

   using (var sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
   {
       sw.Write(json);
       sw.Flush();
       sw.Close();
   }

   try
   {
       var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
       using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
       {
           result = sr.ReadToEnd();
       }
   }

   catch (WebException webex)
   {
       WebResponse errResp = webex.Response;
       using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
       {
           StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
           result = reader.ReadToEnd();
       }
   }

   dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
      var models = jsonObj.master;
   }

   ViewBag.Result = result;
   return View();
}
```

I am completely screwed up!! :(

**EDIT:**

Content of Web.config used on the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx" requirePermission="false" />
        <!--<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />-->
        <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\xxx.mdf;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="xxx" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.xxx.csdl|res://*/Models.xxx.ssdl|res://*/Models.xxx.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=xxx;user id=xxx;password=xxx;TransparentNetworkIPResolution=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="CLXLandingEntities" connectionString=".." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
        <!-- Custom entries -->
        <add key="CryptoKey" value="xxx" />
        <!-- Message Log Keys -->
        <add key="GeneralInquiry" value="abd010e9-f9fe-4e2b-bbc6-b8a3ece2f7a1" />
        <add key="ScheduledTestDrive" value="ddf52846-10bf-415c-a8ea-a44d313a11ad" />
        <add key="MakeAnOffer" value="6d27d834-5ce5-4ea7-b8b6-e38fe16fdba7" />
        <add key="BaseDomain" value="http://basedomain.com/" />

        <!-- Write below key in web.config file when implementing custom membersip. Otherwise, Godaddy would show SSE error-->
        <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />

        <add key="VehicleDescriptionPlaceholderText" value="Respond To This AD For Details" />

        <!-- Site mode-->
        <add key="SiteMode" value="L" />
        <add key="DevEmail" value="xxx@gmail.com" />

        <add key="ManualUploadDisplay" value="On"/>
        <!-- ImageOptim -->
        <add key="imageoptim_username" value="xxx"/>
        <add key="imageoptim_doc" value="https://imageoptim.com/api/get?username=xxx"/>

        <add key="exclude_vehicle_price_in_search" value="10" />

        <add key="public_warranty_sales_person_id" value="xxx"/>
        <add key="public_warranty_default_dealer_id" value="xxx"/>

        <add key="PhotoDefaultWatermark" value="xxx" />

        <!-- Canonical -->
        <add key="RenderCononical" value="YES" />

        <!-- Message Bird -->
        <add key="MessageBirdSubject" value="xxx" />

        <!-- Dealer / Seller / Reseller public page generic tagline-->
        <add key="TagLine" value="Cars for sale."/>

    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <caching>
            <outputCacheSettings>
                <outputCacheProfiles>
                    <add name="CacheCompressedContent10Minutes" duration="600"/>
                </outputCacheProfiles>
            </outputCacheSettings>
        </caching>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <!-- Set session timeout to 1 hour (60 minutes) -->
        <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/login" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>
        <pages  validateRequest="false">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
        <!-- request length (1048 MB) -->
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576"  requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
            <add name="ContentCompresser" type="MinifyContent.ContentCompresser, MinifyContent" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
            <!-- Another option to fix multiple words in URL for deale search. Will look inti it later -->
            <!--<add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="/search-dealers/*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />-->
        </handlers>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="http://example.com/" exactDestination="false" httpResponseStatus="Found" />
        <security>
            <!--
                Resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739233/double-escape-sequence-inside-a-url-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured
                Resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453218/is-enabling-double-escaping-dangerous
            -->
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <!--redirect to https -->
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <!--redirect to https-->
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    </entityFramework>
    <resizer>
        <plugins>
            <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
            <add name="SimpleFilters" />
        </plugins>
    </resizer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: can you post the full web.config?

Comment: Does the user that IIS is running the application under have access to the file?

Comment: i think you have enabled windows authentication. Check your web.config, or post full config here

Comment: Thank you PrashantPimpale, John and Mansur. I have updated my question with `Web.config` content which is running on the server. @MansurAnorboev I am using FormsAuthentication. @John how can I check that?