# IIS is giving 404 - File or directory not found error on my Angular application route

Tags: angular, iis

I have made a deployment of my angular application which was working fine previously, but when i put the inside component of the application to the root module and trying to access it from the top of the application its throwing this error on IIS.

Here is my routing file for angular:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'enable-cookies', component: EnableCookiesComponent },
  { path: 'not-found', component: NotFoundComponent },
  { path: 'lock-screen', component: LockScreenComponent, canLoad: 
    [RestrictPathGuard] },
  { path: 'booking-detail/:id/:id2', loadChildren: 
     './public/public.module#PublicModule'},
  { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/components/pages.module#PagesModule', 
    canActivate: [UserProtectionGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found' }
  ];
```

In the above routes the path **booking-detail/:id/:id2** is giving me the **404** error, the other paths are working fine.

I have also my url rewrite file in web.config below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

 <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
  <rules>
   <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Is there anything I am missing or doing it not properly ?

Below is my url which I am trying to access.

```
http://10.1.1.1:7070/booking-detail/MTk2NnwxMDR8U0VBfEdVRVNU/Dm9duQS%2fI%2fZSLdXyQTyLVZUNRjuTxRjXhGUxecdVifZh%2fhk6cWKIH6chi5pQgr6e3HQ296gGFgRE%2fkpFoW95YgsFCWQuSdeKk79iPFi9RW1RFQfZ4Zr%2fQYZ40r0q%2bzBuDZmVrrxU39Ayn9nGP5%2fNbD7219uff8K5cwsTYkhqxNDjbfZ5SHcPiPXvdyRkDnFpXzsmNq0TjOAPIBqsRkVilmFCWI6tYCxx4brwKO7Acy1EE8TD3p9U6BS%2fZLhZikFkiAhHUKVw8ImLGhctp5TDfg3BIYHMQ7Rj4BEYnEEdpxxRP%2fgB3g%2bvRB4l8sCgJSCc4SVrQIb68lXttzfyEDLLJIzmCVdRDoCnRUqRMuJWSzXQ5m0vcvEhP1p%2bpdSp7OwJQag82YlO%2fv0lIkrSvrMih4auBjEv64%2fFJfYJ7dK%2fGOmBHuh5ET7du13kpKql7k39LrRR4BkzQS4cCswuD8PS6w%3d%3d
```

Here is the routing of PublicModule

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: PublicComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', component: ViewBookingComponent},
    ]
}
```

];

Comment: do you have a <base href="/"> in your index.html ?

Comment: @SGalea Yes I do have that tag in my index.html tag

Comment: can you add the routing of PublicModule to the question ?  I do not think it is an IIS issue, given you managed to get it deployed before however rewrite should be url="/" and base href='/' your issue is angular with routing.

Comment: @SGalea I have added the public module routing

Comment: I've tested with this routing structure and it is working and I'm running out of ideas without seeing things for myself. What I would suggest is adding a button and see if through angular routing works versus URL direct access. Also open the deployed web.config and index.html in a text editor and see if it is what you intend to deploy if you are using some deployment automation. (can never be too sure)

Answer (score 3):

For IIS, add a rewrite rule in Web.config.

Just place the Web.config in the root folder of the application.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you are unfortunate and cannot add that Web.config, use **HashLocationStrategy** as the last resort.

https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy#example

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
```

with

```
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
```

Comment: Are you deploying in some subfolder under some url ?

Comment: Yes I am deploying under a subfolder named UI.

Comment: <base href="/UI/">

Comment: Was this working before when you deployed or it was working only on localhost ? Urls shouldn't be longer than 255 characters. But still the issue you have is unrelated to this.

Comment: Yes It was working fine before, but when i added another module to route which is booking-detail, its started giving error on that particular route but on other routes its still working fine

Comment: ok I just to be sure about something after domain.com/placeholder/booking-detail...   in the place of placeholder. Is there something?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in `chrome` but then I tried to open it in `firefox` and the actual error was that the `iis` was configured to disable double escape sequence so I set configured the requrest filtering to allow double escaping

```
<security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security>
```

and then it works, but be aware of the [security holes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739233/double-escape-sequence-inside-a-url-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured) that this solution will add