# Api is giving 404 when added + as part of URL (%2B)

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core 3.1 and receiving values from URL. Its working fine but when I add "+" sign as a part of URL, it gives 404.
Example : localhost:9000/api/get/%2B12/values

Answer (score 2):

version above IIS7 will refuse to request the URL contains symbols such as '+' by default. The following modifications are required. You need add the following nodes in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

But now the .net core project does not have web.config to configure IIS options. You need to go to the location:

vs project location `/.vs/config/applicationhost.config` to add the above node.

Note that the `.vs` folder is a hidden folder and needs to be set visible.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is a special character. It should ideally be should be URL encoded as `%2B`.
Turns out it's not really required though (like in the screenshot below) but I still recommend it. (See: [URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20))

Here's a working example controller:

```cs
[ApiController]
public class ExpController : Controller
{
    [Route("/api/exp/{arg}/values")]
    public IActionResult Test(int arg) =>
        Ok($"The arg is: {arg}");
}
```

[image]

Note how the route parameter is a `int`. For more complex values (other than just 12, +12, -12; eg: 12+12) the route will need to be a string instead.

Comment: localhost:9000/api/get/%2B12/values

Comment: @Faisal I've added sample code, play around with it.

Comment: I have tried this but only + (%2B) is not working.%2F is working fine.Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1 :

Mess with config to bypass request validation / allowDoubleEscaping (Asp.Net)
You need to be aware for certain risk/vulnabilirities described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53621095/4798459

#### .netcore :

Since this issues is related to IIS, not your solution. You need to handle a web.config

1. Create a new web.config on the root of your project.
2. Right click, properties, set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always"
3. When you publish a .net core app, a "basic web.config" file is created. (For iis)

   - You need to copy the content of the "basic web.config".
   - You can find the auto-generated web.config file:
   - Where your app is already published (local server?)
   - You can also publish your api temporarly to a random path on your PC, see details here https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/401445/dotnet-core-support/publish-net-core-application)

The web.config should like so, i added the  tag with a a commentt

```
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <!-- XML node <security> is added to allow allowDoubleEscaping and add support for + paremeter in a route. Risk:https://stackoverflow.com/a/53621095/4798459 -->
            <security>
                <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"></requestFiltering>
            </security>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments="[.\SolutionName.Namespace.dll]" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

4. Make sure that the step 2 is done before publishing your app otherwise it wont work.
5. Not tested with iisexpress

### Option 2

Change pramater type in the api. Intead of being on the route, use a queryString instead

### Option 3

Custom solution for request filtetring /routing, which i don't have any example, and seems a bit "over the top".

### Option 4, to avoid:

Use an other solution for encoding / decoding special caracter (I have not tried)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55637235/4798459