# Pass data from Angular to .Net Core Web Api with "/" character

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, request, asp.net-core-webapi

I have issue with passing data from angular to webapi.
I need to translate some phrases from my DB and everything works until my phrase looks like this:

> "day w/o break"

Because in this situation my request to webapi looks like:

> https://localhost:44973/api/translation/getResstring/day%20w/o%20break

And that character / destroying the request.
How to pass it to WebApi correctly? I did it in hurry yesterday do encode on Angular side and decode on Web Api side but it not works, so i decided to revert it.

Yesterday attempt, angular app:

```
[...]
public getResstringByPhrase(
source: string
): Observable<string> {
  const result = this.http.get(this.url + "getResstring/" + source, { responseType: 'text' })
  return result
}
[...]
```

.net Core web api:

```
[HttpGet("{*phrase}")]
[Route("getResstring/{phrase}")]
public IActionResult Get(string phrase)
{
  var resstring = _translationRepository.GetResstringByPhrase(phrase);
  return new OkObjectResult(resstring);
}
```

Startup.cs (only Configure):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }

  app.UseHttpsRedirection();

  app.UseRouting();

  app.UseAuthorization();

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
  });
```

}    }

But even with this attempt, it doesn't work with phrases with "/" symbol

#UPDATE

Conflicting action:

```
   [HttpGet("{languageCharset}/{resstring}")]
    [Route("{languageCharset}/{resstring}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string resstring, LanguageCharset languageCharset)
    {
      var translate = _translationRepository.GetTranslatedByResstring(resstring, languageCharset);
      return new OkObjectResult(translate);
    }
```

#UPDATE 2:

I made it, now "/" works, but i have problems with "+". Code

Webapi:

```
[HttpGet("{phrase}")]
    [Route("getResstring/{phrase}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string phrase)
    {
      phrase = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(phrase);
      var resstring = _translationRepository.GetResstringByPhrase(phrase);
      return new OkObjectResult(resstring);
    }
```

Angular app:

```
if( translatedElements[index].getIsTranslated() === false ) {
          this.getResstringByPhrase(encodeURIComponent(translatedElements[index].getValue())).subscribe(async res => {
            const translatedLabel = await this.GetTranslatedByResstring(res, 1045).toPromise()
            if (translatedLabel.getPhrase() !== '') {
              translatedElements[index].setValue(translatedLabel.getPhrase())
            }   
          })
        }
```

And now the error is (only appears when phrase have "+" inside):

HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found

The request filtering module is configured to reject the rejection of the cancellation of an alternate double solution.
(sorry for translation from my language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use asterisk `*` or double asterisk `**` as a prefix to a route parameter:

For example:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class LanguagesController : Controller
{
    [Route("getResstring/{*phrase}")]
    public string GetResstringByPhrase(string phrase)
    {
        return "aa";
    }

}
```

You could send request url like:`https://localhost:44973/api/languages/getResstring/day%20w/o%20break`

Be sure your Startup.cs should be like below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Result(For test,I just use browser to send request.The browser will encode the url automatically):

[image]

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-template-reference

**Update:**

Your code has a mistake.Model could not be passed as route value.It could be passed from query string or from body.So you can't use `[Route("{languageCharset}/{resstring}")]` to pass the model data to the action.

Then,you need use the specific attribute(e.g `[FromQuery]`,`[FromBody]`,`[FromRoute]`) to specify the parameter source from.

The difference between route and query string is that:`https://localhost:44973/api/languages/getResstring?Id=1`,`getResstring` is route value.`?Id=1` is query string.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class LanguagesController : Controller
{
    [Route("getResstring/{*phrase}")]
    public string GetResstringByPhrase(string phrase)
    {
        return "aa";
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{resstring}")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromRoute]string resstring,[FromQuery]LanguageCharset languageCharset)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

### Update 2

For cannot use plus symbol in route,this is an IIS issue:

Please look at the following post:

[double escape sequence inside a url : The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739233/double-escape-sequence-inside-a-url-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured)

You need add the following section in your `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Result:

[image]

**Note:**

If you **do not have web.config file** in your project,you could follow the steps to create it:

1.Right-click your project->choose `Add`->choose `New Item`:

[image]

2.Search `config` in search bar->choose `Web Configuration File`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it gonna work, but look at my updated question. I added * to resstring, but in my attempt to do this, when i debugging i reciving under resstring part of path, in this example it's looke like this : phrase="getResstring/day w/o break" .  I want to get only phrase="day w/o break". If i put it in route, not httpget, i recive "The value 'getResstring' is not valid."

Comment: Hi,why do you add multiple route?In your scenario,it seems you need `[Route("getResstring/{*phrase}")]`.

Comment: Sorry, but i wrote it in edit. If i use [Route("getResstring/{*phrase}")], i reciving "The value 'getResstring' is not valid. It don't even get into this function, so my breakpoint not helps in this situation

Comment: Where did you get this error message?Be sure remove `[HttpGet("{*phrase}")]`.

Comment: You used `[Route("getResstring/{phrase}")]` in your edit not `[Route("getResstring/{*phrase}")]`.Please be carefull.

Comment: Still: "The value 'getResstring' is not valid."

Comment: Could you please share where did you get this error?If you do not hit the endpoints,it only return 404 Http status error.Please learn to set breakpoints to debug the code.

Comment: I did it in next answer

Answer (score 0):

If i type: https://localhost:44397/api/translation/getResstring/polish

Then i recive:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|cfc7e08b-41bcf96eadd38d17.","errors":{"languageCharset":["The value 'getResstring' is not valid."]}}
```

If i type: https://localhost:44397/api/translation/getResstring/day%20w/o%20break

Then i just recive: Page not found

When i remove all *, firt attempt working, second giving the same

Comment: What is your version of asp.net core?

Comment: And please edit the thread and share your detailed code.Not sure what is your `languageCharset`.Did you do any other things in your action?Please check your project,there is no same endpoint.

Comment: Check your action in your project,if it needs a parameter contains `languageCharset` property.

Comment: I guess it may caused by this line:`_translationRepository.GetResstringByPhrase`.Be sure you only have `[Route("getResstring/{*phrase}")]` in your action.Do not use any of `[HttpGet("{*phrase}")]` or `[Route("getResstring/{phrase}")]`.

Comment: I fixed, sorry about that but i pasted wrong method in angular side, now it's fixed in my question. Yes, atm i have only [Route("getResstring/{*phrase}")] and it still doesnt work

Comment: Only if you share the detailed code then we will resolve your issue.Otherwise,it always work in my prokect.I suggest that you could create a new repo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: But i posted full path to api, it works until i add "/" to the searched string, so the problem is with it, if you want how i making request, it look like it in postman: https://localhost:44397/api/translation/getResstring/polski and it shoud return string, but after added * it not works

Comment: Please answer my previous questions.You never answer my question and only said does not work.I need ask again.What is your version of asp.net core?And your error message have a field named `languageCharset`.That is to say,you may have an action which contains a parameter and it has model validation.Please check carefully.All of these you need share with us.Also,what is your Startup.cs.How do you configure the route template(what I did I have provided in my answer)?

Comment: Ok, now i know the answer. It not used in this request, but used in other request in api where route looks like this: [Route("{languageCharset}/{resstring}")] It looks like it not going to my getResstring api methot, but to the other because of * char inside path

Comment: Yes.That is what I said in my previous comment.Remember to avoid using conflict endpoint.Then using what my answer did.It will work well as mine.If my answer helped you,remember to accept as answer.

Comment: Ok, i added startup.cs (important part) to question

Comment: You said you have found the answer.So you need share the conflict action:`but used in other request in api where route looks like this: [Route("{languageCharset}/{resstring}")]`.

Comment: Done in question

Comment: Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Please give me some minutes.

Comment: Ok, im waiting.

Comment: Hi @Obyi,Your code has a mistake.Model could not be passed from route value.It could be passed from query string or from body.So you can't use [Route("{languageCharset}/{resstring}")] to pass the model data to the action.Check my updated answer.And check my updated gif.It will help you understand the code.

Comment: @Rena Hey, check my updated answer #Update 2. I figured out how to fix problem with "/", but now i have issue "+"

Comment: Hi @Obyi,check my Update 2 answer.Actually it is a new issue.The previous issue I have helped you resolve it.Remember to accept as answer.